# Codeigniter date comparision

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I have searched the forum, but can't get this query to work. It returns an empty array. If I remove the `WHERE` parts, it works fine...

This is the output with `$this->db->last_query()`:

```
  SELECT `buchungen`.*, `rechnungen`.`sent_count`, `rechnungen`.`zahlungsdatum`, `rechnungen`.`last_modified`
  FROM (`buchungen`)
  LEFT JOIN `rechnungen` ON `rechnungen`.`buchungs_id` = `buchungen`.`id`
  WHERE `buchungen`.`datum` >= '2016-03-13 12:00:00'
  AND `buchungen`.`datum` <= '2016-03-13 12:00:00'
```

Comment: You are comparing a string that cannot be greater or less, only integers can do that. Use the function `DATE('2016-03-13 12:00:00')`

Comment: What is the data type of the `datum` field?

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
SELECT `buchungen`.*, `rechnungen`.`sent_count`, `rechnungen`.`zahlungsdatum`, rechnungen.last_modified
FROM (`buchungen`) 
LEFT JOIN `rechnungen` ON `rechnungen`.`buchungs_id` = `buchungen`.`id` 
WHERE `buchungen`.`datum` BETWEEN CAST('2016-03-13 12:00:00' AS DATETIME) 
AND CAST('2016-03-13 12:00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

-Assuming you're saving `datum` as `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->query("SELECT buchungen.*, rechnungen.sent_count, rechnungen.zahlungsdatum, rechnungen.last_modified
                  FROM buchungen
                  LEFT JOIN rechnungen 
                  ON rechnungen.buchungs_id = buchungen.id
                  WHERE buchungen.datum >=  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2016-03-13 12:00:00'))
                  AND buchungen.datum <= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2016-03-13 12:00:00'))");
```

Comment: Did you check this??